# Проблема с обработчиками в цикле

Tags: javascript, циклы

Есть два массива, которые расположены в специальном порядке. Мне надо, чтобы при boxNav[0] в функцию noneWrap передавался элемент массива displayWrapper[0]. То есть, если:

```
boxNav[1] = noneWrapper(displayWrapper[1])
boxNav[2] = noneWrapper(displayWrapper[2])
boxNav[3] = noneWrapper(displayWrapper[3])
```

Но блин получается какая-то ересь с j в обработчике:

```
var boxNav = [ document.getElementById('page_groups'),
               document.getElementById('human_groups'),
               document.getElementById('group_groups'),
               document.getElementById('worker_groups') ];

var displayWrapper = [ document.getElementById('idol_page'),
                       document.getElementById('idol_user'),
                       document.getElementById('in_group'),
                       document.getElementById('my_fans') ];

for(var j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
  boxNav[j].addEventListener('click', function(){

    noneWrapper( displayWrapper[j] );
    alert(j);                 // == 4
    alert(displayWrapper[j]); // == undefined

    this.firstChild.style.color = 'white';
    this.style.backgroundColor  = '#597DA3';
    restartGroupNav(this);

  },false);
}
```

Почему такое происходит и как сделать, чтобы работало нормально?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

всё дело в замыканях, когда вы выполняете в цикле

```
boxNav[j].addEventListener('click', function(){
    // ...
    ... j
    // ...
})
```

переменная j "замыкается"(не копируется, для всех хендлеров - будет использована одна и та же переменная), но в цикле вы её инкрементируете, т.о. всегда получается конечное значение.

самый простой способ избежать этого - IIFE:

```
for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++){ // почему вы используете префиксный инкремент?

    boxNav[j].addEventListener('click', (function(i){
        return function(){
            noneWrapper(displayWrapper[i]);
            alert(i)
            // ...
        }
    }(j)),false)
}
```

или так:

```
for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++){ 
    (function(i){
        boxNav[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            noneWrapper(displayWrapper[i]);
            alert(i)
            // ...
        },false);
    }(j))
}
```

или так:

```
boxNav.forEach(function(box, idx){
    box.addEventListener('click', function(){
        noneWrapper(displayWrapper[idx]);
        alert(idx)
        // ...
    },false);
});
```