# Что в Javascript значит синтакс ( function(){...} )( param1, param2); ?

Tags: javascript, функции

Столкнулся в [этом примере](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) с синтаксисом, который раньше не встречал:

```
for (var state in aus) {
    ...
    (function (st, state) {
        ...
    })(aus[state], state);
}
```

Что означает эта конструкция внутри цикла?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Чтобы избежать недостоверных данных, которых в данном треде достаточно, вставлю и свои пять копеек:

на подобный вопрос я уже отвечал - [Проблема с обработчиками в цикле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167570/), только там подобный синтаксис был решением проблемы

собственно, что это IIFE - Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, и для чего её можно применять уже описано здесь же, но почему этот подоход используется именно в скрипте из ссылки:

```
for (var state in aus) {
    ...
    (function(st, state) {
        st[0].onmouseover = function() {  
            /* мы знаем, что функция onmouseover - асинхронная, т.е. мы не можем достоверно сказать когда она выполнится, но точно после выполнения цикла, следоватльно, после выполнения цикла aus[state] - будет указывать на последнее значение, которые было получено в цикле, что не соответсвует нашим ожиданиям, для этого aus[state] копируется в переменную st, которая на каждой итерации  цикла указывает на необходимый aus[state], тоже самое с переменной state*/
            ...
        };
        st[0].onmouseout = function() {
            /*здесь ситуация аналогичная*/
            ...
        }
    })(aus[state], state);
}
```

поэтому всегда, когда в цикле оперируем с асинхронными функциями, будь то таймауты, обработчики событий или колбэки, всегда искользуется подобная техника

- [Тонкости ECMA-262-3. Часть 6. Замыкания.](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-chapter-6-closures/)

Answer (score 8):

Это сделано чтобы не засорять глобальную область видимости локальными переменными и и меть копии самых важных глобальных например в JQuery. То есть:

```
(function(window, undefined){
   var a = 28.2;
   var z = new Object();
   //...  
   window.myVal = a != undefined;       
})(window);
```

Этот код в глобальную область видимости добавляет только `myVal` и имеет собственный экземпляр `window` и `undefined` (`undefined` не ключевое слово а глобальная переменная)  на случай если кто то напишет после исполнения этого кода:

```
 window = 1; undefined = "Hack";
```

то (если ф -ции не передаются аргументы они принимают значение `undefined`) у нас будет *истинное значение `undefined`* и *истинное значение `window`*.

Эта и подобные темы неоднократно обсуждались в том числе и мной и я в конечном счёте пришёл к выводу что чтобы **понять** JS нужно прочитать `JavaScript The definitive guide`

Comment: Чтобы понять JS одних книжек мало. Нужна еще практика. undefined в современных браузерах уже давно non-writable. То есть неперезаписываемая. Но ты все равно молодец. В 16 лет я даже не знал, что такое JavaScript.

Comment: > undefined в современных браузерах уже давно non-writable

@Lucky а ещё в современных браузерах можно установить её атрибуты и сделать writable :) (читайте указанную книгу последнее издание)

Comment: Атрибуты бывают у объектов. undefined это примитив. У него не может быть свойств. Книжки надо читать внимательнее все таки.

Comment: :) покрутяжничать не вышло :) но я если честно сам эту книгу лишь скачал не читал но сейчас времени катастрофически не хватает (я пытаюсь и на C++ время оставлять и на Assembler) а ещё у нас на форуме был (а может есть но под другим ником) 15 летний @Asen который знал (и объяснял другим - что это подтверждало) JS/JQuery C++ Java Pascal Delphi Phyton PHP и то как в windows происходит вызов ф-ций .dll а ещё есть @Котик который знает наверное всё что знают всё учасники этого форума вместе взятые imho :)

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Я_знаю,_что_ничего_не_знаю

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы было понятней:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  var j = i;
  setTimeout( function(){console.log(j);} , 100)
}
```

Выведет десять девяток.

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  (function(j){
     setTimeout( function(){console.log(j);} , 100)
  })(i);
}
```

Выведет числа от 0 до 9.

Answer (score 5):

Единственный полный, корректный и емкий ответ был у **Spectre**. Его и надо слушать.
Тот приём, который использован в топике называется Immediately-Invoked Function Expression и используется для того, чтобы ассинхронные коллбеки внутри цикла могли получить ссылку на корректный элемент.

*По остальным комментариям*

> P.S. в примере автора НЕ замыкание, перепутал.

И опять перепутали, в примере автора замыкание. И вообще любая функция создаёт замыкание. Например, внутри функции можно получить доступ к `aus`. Это и достигается замыканием. Читаем, например, JavaScript-Garden:

> Одним из самых мощных инструментов JavaScript'а считаются возможность создавать замыкания — это такой приём, когда наша область видимости всегда имеет доступ к внешней области, в которой она была объявлена. Собственно, единственный механизм работы с областями видимости в JavaScript — это функции: т.о. объявляя функцию, вы автоматически реализуете замыкания

**ivanpopelyshev** правильно понял вопрос, но привёл только пример, не объяснив идеи

Ответ **Rules** вообще мимо. Конечно, иногда функции используются для этого, но тут не тот случай:

> Это сделано чтобы не засорять глобальную область видимости локальными переменными и и меть копии самых важных глобальных например в JQuery.

И самый главный ответ **`heavy_metal_fan`**, который так критиковал **Spectre** и совершенно правильно. Я прям вспомнил годы своей бурной молодости, 2-й курс университета, когда я глубоко не понимаю, это грёбанное "Экономико-математическое моделирование", но экзамен писать надо и пишу всё, что попадётся в шпорах.

Основная проблема этого ответа - огромное количество воды и совершенно левой информации. Это бездумно скопированных кусок книги и это ярко видно на первых двух абзацах:

> Это называется Closure или Wrapper.
>
> Как указано выше, по мимо
> использования оригинальных глобальных
> обьектов внутри тела функции,
> возиожности Closure далеко не
> ограничеваются на этом. Это лишь малая
> часть применения

Мы ещё не начали читать комментарий, а он уже отсылает куда-то в прошлое, куда-то в пустоту. Комментарий отлично пересказывает главу какой-то книги, возможно даже хорошей, например Флагнана или Резига. Но вы вывалили сюда ВСЁ про функции. Кусок про **Предназначение №1 - Имитация NameSpace**, кусок про **Предназначение №2 - Имитация класса**, кусок про **Предназначение №3 - модификация существующих переменных**

Вы понемногу дошли до ключевой фразы, которая является правильным ответом на вопрос топик-стартера - **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression**, но потом, в объяснениях снова скатились не туда.

Основной недостаток этого ответа не в том, что он - некорректный по своей сути. Нет, я уверен, что книга, с которой вы это всё скопировали может быть очень хорошей (**кстати, что это за книга?**), но в нём нет ответа на вопрос в топике, который дал, например, **Spectre**.

Answer (score 4):

Создается анонимная функция и сразу же вызывается.

Answer (score 4):

Эта конструкция называется [функциональным выражением](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-chapter-5-functions/#funktsiya-vyirajenie-function-expression). Все, что оборачивается в скобки в JavaScript считается выражением. Если скобки убрать, получим ошибку объявления функции без указания имени функции. Например хром выведет такую ошибку:

```
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`
```