# !function(){...} что за конструкция в js

Tags: javascript, функции

`!function(){...}`

Что делает данная конструкци? 
 Зачем здесь отрицание перед обьявлением функции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что в Javascript значит синтакс ( function(){...} )( param1, param2); ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189242/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81-function-param1-param2)

Answer (score 6):

Скорее всего вы забыли еще одни скобки

```
!function(){}();
```

Это немедленный вызов функции. Также вместо `!` можно использовать любую унарную операцию. Используется для вызова функции в месте определения если не нужно сохранять результат. Если нужно сохранить результат, обычно используют такую конструкцию

```
result = function(){}();
```

Comment: Но ведь можно и просто сразу анонимную функцию вызвать даже если не надо результат сохранять function(){...}() зачем усложнять восприятие и ставить унарный оператор "!" чето все не догоню)

Comment: @Дима К сожалению вызвать функцию так `function(){}();` не получится. Интерпретатор посчитает это неправильным объявлением фунуции

Comment: !function(){...}() более читабельно чем: (function(){})();

Comment: @VladVityuk Мне кажется это дело привычки. Мне лично больше нравится `+function...`